# leetcode: decode ways dp solution

Tags: dynamic-programming, decode

leetcode: decode ways

I tried using dp to optimize my recursion, however it seems does not work well since the running time has exceeded the limit. Can anyone help me with the code and tell me what has gone wrong with the dp?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numDecodings(string s) {
        
        int totalnum;
        *map<string, int> dp;*
        stringstream ss;
        int sint;
        string s11=s.substr(0,2);
        stringstream geek(s11);
        geek>>sint;
        if(dp[s]){
            totalnum=dp[s];
        }
        else if(s[0]=='0'){
            return 0;
        }else if(sint>26){
            string s1=s.substr(1,s.length()-1);
            totalnum=numDecodings(s1);
        }
        else
        {
        if(s.length()==1){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(s.length()==2){
            string s1=s.substr(1,s.length()-1);
            if(s[s.length()-1] !=0){totalnum=numDecodings(s1)+1;}
            else{totalnum=numDecodings(s1);}
        }
        else if(s.length()>2){
            string s1=s.substr(1,s.length()-1);
            string s2=s.substr(2,s.length()-2);
            totalnum=numDecodings(s1)+numDecodings(s2);}
        }
        
        *dp.insert(pair<string, int>(s, totalnum));*
        return totalnum;
    }
};
```

Comment: you would get more views if you use at least a language tag for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two states an index can have: as the first digit or the second digit. Try to avoid creating more strings in a solution.

```py
class Solution:
    def numDecodings(self, s: str) -> int:
      if s[0] == '0':
        return 0

      dp = [[0, 0] for i in range(len(s) + 1)]

      dp[0][0] = 1
      dp[1][0] = 1

      for i in range(1, len(s)):
        # zero must be second
        if s[i] == '0':
          if s[i-1] not in ['1', '2']:
            return 0
          dp[i+1] = [0, dp[i][0]]
  
        elif '00' < s[i-1:i+1] < '27' and s[i-1] != '0':
          dp[i+1] = [sum(dp[i]), sum(dp[i-1])]
    
        else:
          dp[i+1] = [sum(dp[i]), 0]
    
      return sum(dp[len(s)])
```